# Powershell: Passing an array of objects (SSRS.ReportingServices.CatalogItem) to a function

Tags: c#, powershell, reporting-services

I am managing a new instance of SSRS using PowerShell. I have written a long script which works, but I'd like to break it down into functions.

The first step is to get a list of reports on the server. I use a function to do this.

```
function Get-ReportList {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Server,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Type
    )

    try {
        $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Server -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2010 -UseDefaultCredential -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "Unable to create Proxy at " $Server
    }
        
    $Reports = $Proxy.ListChildren($Path,$true) | Where-Object{$_.typename -eq $Type} 

    # Output the list of reports
    $Reports
}
```

Next I created a function that takes the output of the above function and exports it to a CSV file. According to the Microsoft documentation the ReportingService2010 method ListChildren returns an array of CatalogItem. I explicitly declare my input parameter to be an array of CatalogItems.

```
$ReportList = Get-ReportList -Server $MyServer -Path $MyPath  -Type 'Report'

function Write-ReportList {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][SSRS.ReportingService2010.CatalogItem[]]$ReportList,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$CSVPath
    )

    $ReportList | Export-Csv -Path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
}

Write-ReportList -ReportList $ReportList -CSVPath "MyPath"
```

Executing the above gives a perplexing message saying it can't convert a type to itself:

```
Write-ReportList : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ReportList'. Cannot convert the 
"SSRS.ReportingService2010.CatalogItem" value of type "SSRS.ReportingService2010.CatalogItem" to type 
"SSRS.ReportingService2010.CatalogItem".
```

FWIW, the code

```
$ReportList | Export-Csv -Path "MyPath" -NoTypeInformation
```

works on its own, but I can't find a way to wrap it inside a function. There are several more functions I'd like to create which accept a list of such objects. Is there a way I can make my desired functionality work?

Comment: "Next I created a function that takes the output of the above function and exports it to a CSV file." Why? `Export-Csv` already exists :-)

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I would like to create similar functions that take report lists as input and do more complicated things. I tried this trivial function as a test.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I found a solution: use **pscustomobject** instead of an explicit type.

```
$ReportList = Get-ReportList -Server $MyServer -Path $MyPath  -Type 'Report'

function Write-ReportList {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][pscustomobject[]]$ReportList,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$CSVPath
    )

    $ReportList | Export-Csv -Path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
}

Write-ReportList -ReportList $ReportList -CSVPath "MyPath"
```

The script works.